# C++: class that has a pointer to a function as an attribute

Tags: c++, function, parameters, function-pointers

I have a Button class:

```
class Button : public Component {

private:
    SDL_Rect box;
    void* function;

public:
    Button( int x, int y, int w, int h, void (*function)() );
    ~Button();
    void handleEvents(SDL_Event event);

};
```

And I want to execute `Button::function` in the method `Button::handleEvents`:

```
void Button::handleEvents(SDL_Event event) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    // If user clicked mouse
    if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            // Get mouse offsets
            x = event.button.x;
            y = event.button.y;

            // If mouse inside button
            if( ( x > box.x ) && ( x < box.x + box.w ) && ( y > box.y ) && ( y < box.y + box.h ) )
            {
                this->function();
                return;
            }
    }

}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
Button.cpp: In the constructor ‘Button::Button(int, int, int, int, void (*)(), std::string)’:
Button.cpp:17:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
Button.cpp: In the function ‘virtual void Button::handleEvents(SDL_Event)’:
Button.cpp:45:19: error: can't use ‘((Button*)this)->Button::function’ as a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function pointer in your private section is not declared as it should be.

It should be :

```
void (*functionPtr)();
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) question for more info.

Comment: When I destroy an object from class "Button", should I do something with that pointer?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 2):

In your class variable declarations, you have

```
void* function;
```

This declares a variable named `function` which is a pointer to `void`. To declare it as a function pointer, you need the same syntax as that in your parameter list:

```
void (*function)();
```

This is now a pointer to a function which returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `std::function<void()>` for this kind of purpose:

```
#include <functional>

class Button : public Component
{
private:
    SDL_Rect box;
    std::function<void()> function;

public:
    Button( int x, int y, int w, int h, std::function<void()> f);
    ~Button();
    void handleEvents(SDL_Event event);
};

void Button::handleEvents(SDL_Event event)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    // If user clicked mouse
    if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        // Get mouse offsets
        x = event.button.x;
        y = event.button.y;
        // If mouse inside button
        if( ( x > box.x ) && ( x < box.x + box.w ) && ( y > box.y ) && ( y < box.y + box.h ) )
        {
            function();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might change the field declaration,

```
void * function; // a void ptr
void (*function)(); // a ptr to function with signature `void ()`
```

or use a cast:

```
((void (*)())this->function)();
```